# "Социальная игра" - что это?

Tags: семантика

Интересует значение термина "социальный" в сочетании "социальная игра".

Я с трудом перевариваю сочетание "социальная сеть" (в русском есть нормальное слово "публичный", чем оно-то не подошло?), но смирился. Но вот с играми совсем не понимаю. Можно ли сказать, что всякая игра, в которую играют в социальных сетях ("Кто дальше плюнет", например) является игрой социальной? И наоборот, можно ли играть в социальные игры вне социальной сети? Если да, то чем такая игра заслужила титул социальный?

(+)=============== добалено 08.05.2020

Новичок задал вопрос. Я его сюда перетащу, поскольку в комментарий его преобразовывать - замучаешься. Из-за обилия текста.

> Извините что не совсем по теме (на главный вопрос уже ответили), но
>   почему собственно вы считаете слово "публичный" лучше слова
>   "социальный"? Оно не более русское, и более того - оба слова
>   заимствованы из одного и того же языка - латыни.

"Публичный" лучше слова "социальный" по той простой причине, что оно в этом значении давно обкатано языком.  "Социальный" же отсылает к своему основному значению (Свойственный обществу, связанный с жизнью и отношениями людей в обществе), которое здесь не очень применимо.

> Если жить по заветам
>   Норы Галь и заменять заимствованные слова на русские, то правильнее
>   тут будет "общественные сети", "общественные игры".

Как-нибудь без заветов обойдемся.

> "общественные сети", "общественные игры".

Ну так не очень-то здорово получается.

*Сделаю небольшой оффтоп. Слова "социальный" и "общественный" лишь частичные синонимы. Помните Аристотелевское определение человека, данное им в ответ на двуногое без перьев - и прочую платоновскую чепуху?! По Аристотелю - человек животное социальное. "Общественное" здесь не катит. Корова в стаде - тоже общественное. Но не социальное. Социальность предполагает порождение мыслящим обществом...*

Короче, общественные игры - это совсем не то.

> А если уж
>   сравнивать "публичный" и "социальный", то "публичный" имеет неприятный
>   оттенок: не говоря даже о публичных домах - это некий акцент на
>   выставлении на публику своей приватности, потрохов так сказать.

Вы о публичных библиотеках чего-нибудь слышали? А ведь это именно то, с чего слово "публичный" получило путевку в широкую жизнь.

> Да и
>   сочетание "публичная сеть" будет не совсем верным. Можно сказать
>   "публичная страница". А "сеть" - это про связи, и на связях больше
>   акцентирует как раз слово "социальный".

Так мы уже пришли к выводу, что связи здесь вообще ни при чем. Именно некорректность перенесения значения "социальный" из сети на игру и было одним, едва ли не главным, поводом усомниться в удачности термина.

Comment: Извините что не совсем по теме (на главный вопрос уже ответили), но почему собственно вы считаете слово "публичный" лучше слова "социальный"? Оно не более русское, и более того - оба слова заимствованы из *одного и того же* языка - латыни. Если жить по заветам Норы Галь и заменять заимствованные слова на русские, то правильнее тут будет "общественные сети", "общественные игры". А если уж сравнивать "публичный" и "социальный", то "публичный" имеет неприятный оттенок: не говоря даже о публичных домах - это некий акцент на выставлении на публику своей приватности, потрохов так сказать. Да и сочет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Социальные игры — это игры, направленные на социальное взаимодействие. Не все игры в социальных сетях на него направлены, поэтому не любую игру там можно назвать социальной. Например, в шахматы можно поиграть и в интернете, есть рейтинги, соперничество с людьми, но так как эти люди никак не влияют на твой результат, игра не является социальной. А есть игры, где без наличия друзей в игре комфортно играть не получится ("Ферма", например), они-то и называются социальными. Причём, в отличие от командных игр, цель не объединение, не суммарная победа команды, а индивидуальный прогресс с помощью коллектива.

В оффлайне социальных игр не существует (если не считать игрой саму жизнь), ближе всего к ним ролевые игры маленьких детей ("дочки-матери", "доктор" и пр.), но, в отличие от социальных, в ролевых играх нет элемента соревнования.

Comment: Вот это мне нравится, "тепло". А то ведь, если взять за определение некоторые ***свойства*** таких игр страшно становится: например "бесконечная", "не имеющая цели", "игра ради игры" - а ведь 99% игр? называемых социальными, именно такие, но это же не определения никак, сути не раскрывает. Я правильно понимаю, что "социальная" - игра при наличии достаточно большого участников, предполагающая единственной обязательной целью общение по игровым и околоигровым моментам?

Comment: @behemothus да, вы меня поняли верно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже не нравится этот термин, хотя, если вдуматься, он передаёт суть игры. Социальная игра - не только игра в социальных сетях, это **коллективная** игра в группе, то есть термин употребляется в первом значении, связанном со словом "социум". http://my-dictionary.ru/word/32376/socialnyj/
1. см. социум.

2.Общественный, относящийся к жизни людей и их отношениям в обществе. Социальная среда. Социальное положение. Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка.
м.

А социум - коллектив людей, характеризующийся общностью социальной, экономической и культурной жизни.

Любая игра в команде, в группе - социальная. А игры в социальных сетях меня, например, достают именно этой социальностью. Зайдёшь в "Одноклассники" на 15 минут пообщаться с дальними друзьями,а там тебя в 10 игр приглашают: "Зайди в игру, нужна твоя помощь". Уже в статусе писала:"В игры не приглашать, ни во что не играю", начала некоторых из друзей удалять, раз не понимают.

И сеть, наверное, тоже более социальная, а не публичная, ведь сеть характеризуется общностью интересов, у неё свои правила, им должны все подчиняться, как в любом коллективе.
Только я бы игры всё же назвала просто групповыми или коллективными, но ведь нас не спрашивают, когда называют, будем привыкать.

Comment: Людмила, это все очень хорошо разжевано, только я не вижу четкого определения термина. Командные соревнования по шашкам в Интернете  - игра социальная?  А дочки-матери в бабушкином сарае?А что нравится - или не нравится, так другой вопрос, пока не понятно, что это такое, я не стал бы использовать вообще эмоциональные/субъективные оценки